# WPF transparent ListView background with non transparent ListViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to make a WPF ListView with half-transparent background (it has a color filling and 0.5 opacity) but I want its items to not be half-transparent (to have 1 opacity). The problem is that whenever I set ListViewItems' opacity higher than ListView's, it doesn't work. For example when I set it to 1 it still stays at 0.5 because that's its mother object's opacity. Is there some workaround to make it work like I want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mess with the `Opacity` property of the ListView object.  Set it's background color to #80'your RGB values here'.  Basically, use the RGB values of the color you want and set the A(alpha) value to half-transparent, which is 80 in hex.

That will then have no impact on the opacity of the ListView items.

Opacity is good for when you want **everything** to be translucent.  If you need more fine-grained control, which you do in your case, then you are much better served by using the Alpha channel in the individuals items' color/fill/background properties.  In WPF a hexidecimal representation of a color is: #ARGB, where each of those letters are a two-digit hex value representing values from 0 to 255 in decimal.  A is the Alpha channel, R is the Red channel, G is the Green channel, and B is the Blue channel.

For example `#FF808080` is a fully opaque medium gray, and `#01FFFFFF`is an **almost** completely transparent white.  That second one is particularly useful when you want something to look transparent (or at least to expose the color(s) behind it,) yet you still want to be able to click on it.  Items that are 100% transparent are not click-able.

Comment: #80'102, 102, 102' is not a valid token is what I get when I try that.

Comment: If that's the color you want, you need to use `#80666666`.  You have to use Hex values.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Are there any other bonus things I could add to my hex value to modify the color? Or rather, what are the bonus values called so I can look for them myself? Is it best practice to not use opacity at all unless you use non transparent images?

Comment: The hex value is just four hex octets: one for each of the Alpha (transparency), Red, Green, and Blue channels, all of which have a value in the range of `0-255` inclusive.  `0x80` is hex for `128`, which is 50% alpha (128 / 255 ~= 0.5).  The RGB values of `102` are each represented as `0x66` in hex.  The color with `A=0x80 R=0x66 G=0x66 B=0x66` is written as `#80666666`.  The octet for the alpha channel is optional, and if you leave it off, it's assumed to be `FF` (fully opaque).  That's all there is; there aren't any 'bonus' values :).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by defining a custom `ControlTemplate` where you set the `Opacity` property of the `Border` element and put the `ItemsPresenter` on top of this one. Here is an example for you:

```
<ListView Height="100" Background="Yellow">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                                    Opacity="0.5">
                            </Border>
                            <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <ListViewItem Background="Yellow">1</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Background="Yellow">2</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Background="Yellow">3</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

[image]